# representing 2 numbers in 8 bits

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit

I have 2 sets of values.  Each is in the range of -50 to + 50.

Is there any way to represent two of these values in a single byte?
 (I am working in C, using Vstudio 2010).
Thank you.

Clarification: the values are arbitrary integers; that is, the values can be
any integer between -50 and +50.  (So, question has been answered: it is "no".)

Comment: No.  There are 101*101=10201 different possible values.  A byte can only hold 256 different values.

Comment: No, you can represent a maximum of 15 in 4 bits (unsigned). 1111 = 15

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, I'm flat-out retarded and actually believed that would fit! Time for bed. (Maybe if the bits are very large...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not in 8 bits. -50 to +50 is 101 possibilities. With two of them, that's 10201 possibilities. 8 bits only has 256 combinations.

You will need a minimum of 14 bits to store two values -50 to +50.

Comment: The OP did not explicitly state nor imply those values are arbitrary integers in the range from -50 to +50.

Comment: The OP hasn't stated otherwise. Yes, you can read between the lines, but most of us answered based on the assumption that they are arbitrary integers between -50 to 50.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It depends on several things:

- what kind of values those values in the range of -50 to +50 are
- how many bits there are in a byte

If those values from -50 to +50 are arbitrary floating point or integer numbers, you may not be able to fit 2 of them in a single byte. Whether or not that is the case depends on the number of bits in a byte. In Visual C++ bytes are 8-bit. 8 bits are too few for arbitrary integers from -50 to +50 as it has been explained by other people. On some platforms bytes can be as large as 16 bits. In that case, obviously, you can pack several integers from -50 to +50 into 16 bits. AFAIK, you can't have floating point numbers as small as 16 bits or smaller in C/C++.

Now, if those values from -50 to +50 are not arbitrary floating point or integer values, if those values can only be either -50 or +50, 1 bit is enough for one such value. If they can only be -50, 0 or +50, 2 bits are enough for one such value. If they can only be -50, -25, 0, +25 or +50, 3 bits are enough for one such value.

The point is, the answer largely depends on how the question is formulated. Your question does not explicitly define the values in the range from -50 to +50 as arbitrary integers or arbitrary floating point numbers, nor does it imply that kind of values. Unless your question is clarified, there's no single definitive answer such as `yes` or `no`, the best you can get is `maybe`.

Answer (score 0):

-50 to 50 means a range of 100. You need at list 7 bits to represent a range of 100 (7 bits, 128 values, 6 bits, 64 values). So with 8 bits, can't keep full precision and have 2 numbers. If you are ok with loosing precision, then, can do.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is no.

Long answer is, that on most architectures, a byte is 8 bits. Half that is 4 bits. 4 bits can only represent -8 to 7, using twos complement, which is the dominant means of representing ints in most architectures..